# Help uninstalling Ubuntu LTS

Tags: partitioning, uninstall

First of all, I'm sorry if this specific question has been addressed, but I couldn't find all of the details I needed in other questions.

I have Windows 10 installed on my C drive and Ubuntu LTS installed on my D drive. I want to uninstall Ubuntu LTS from my D drive as this is not my main computer anymore.

From my understanding, I believe I can delete the partition on the D drive going through disk management in Windows? However, there are also files on my D drive that I don't want to lose. How can I ensure I don't lose any important files when I uninstall Ubuntu?

Thanks for any of the help, and I apologize if this answer can be found elsewhere.

Edit: Some additional details I forgot to mention are I'm not trying to reinstall Windows onto the D drive, but just trying to delete Ubuntu off of it. Also, the D drive doesn't show up on my computer when I'm logged into Windows, but I believe it shows up under disk management as Disk 1. In disk management, there are two partitions, one that is about 250 megabytes and another that is around 370 gigabytes. I could delete the 250-megabyte partition as I believe that is the Ubuntu LTS OS? I just don't want to accidentally delete any of the other data on the drive as well.

Comment: Make sure you restore Windows as default boot before you do anything with fixMBR if BIOS. If grub is in control and you delete Ubuntu, then the small part to grub in MBR just hangs. If UEFI you have to reset UEFI to make Windows default boot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll go ahead and try out these solutions and see if they help out!

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps will be:

1 - Copy files from your D drive to somewhere that won't be deleted
2 - Delete and repartition your drive to be a single drive again, (you will need repartitioning software for this and as far as I know it is not supported under Windows without third party software.  I'd suggest Gparted [here](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php) to do this (make a USB stick with it, boot from there and repartition.
3 - Boot back into windows and confirm it worked.

Note:  Repartitioning used to be considered dangerous, as with all things it pays to have a backup, though this is fairly safe these days, there's still a chance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The main problem is I don't have direct access to the files in the D drive since it doesn't show up when I boot Windows. As soon as I figure out how to get access to it, I'll try out the steps you mentioned.

Comment: Hi I think you're slightly missing the point.  You don't need to see the D dtive under windows.  Unless you're saying that you don't know how to get your files off the LInux partition?  That's quite a different question.  Boot up to LInux and copy the files you need to a USB stick.  You could also download a 'bootable' OS (runs off USB or CD) such as Knoppix to get this done if you've lost access to the Linux OS.  Make sure the USB stick is formatted to a fat based file system as it's supported by LInux and Windows natively and you can read and write in both Operating Systems.